# PostgreSQL, Replace by Enum

Tags: postgresql

I have int type column with all values from 0 to -5.

Is it possible to make in query some "enum" that instead of integer value I get in result text "ZERO, ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE" based on values 0, -1, -2, -3, -4 and -5, without adding functions to PostgreSQL server and without changing data in table.

If do how that query should look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case the_column
         when 0 then 'ZERO'
         when -1 then 'ONE'
         when -2 then 'TWO'
         when -3 then 'THREE'
         when -4 then 'FOUR'
         when -5 then 'FIVE'
       end as value_label
from the_table
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/48b69/1

The above will return `null` in case any other value is stored in `the_column`. If you don't want that, you need to add an `else` part to the `case` to return some default value (e.g. `unknown`)

Comment: Thanks 'name', since this column is between others and I have existing SELECT after removing SELECT in front of CASE I get wanted result. Why do you put AS value_label? For me query work without that.

Comment: @user973238: this is just to give that expression a proper name. If you can live with the column heading `?column?` that's fine as well.

Comment: Yes I can since I use that through NET where I give custom names to columns in data grid.